# How can I improve the accuracy of my non-linear least squares solver for astronomical spectra?

Tags: python, math, dataset, least-squares, astronomy

I am trying to make my Linear Least Squares Regression code more accurate. It will be working on optical spectra and so the data is very messy and noisy, but right now I'm working on a toy model whose coefficients are known (because I generated them, multiplied them by the template, added a gaussian error, and used that as a fake 'observed spectra'). My least square soln is consistently close to the known coefficients, but never exactly correct. It may be good enough for less sensitive data, but I need to make it more accurate.

```
def solve_p(obs, temp):
    return np.dot((np.dot(lin.inv(np.dot(temp.T,temp)),temp.T)),obs)
```

Shown above is the code I have, and I have also tried with `scipy.linalg.lstsq()`. Neither of these functions give me exactly the right coefficient, and when I find the reduced chi-square value, I get values ranging from 1.25 to 1000. For example, when the known coefficient for a template is 0.7, the least squares solution this comes up with is 0.69981902, and when I use `scipy.linalg.lstsq()`, I get the same thing. I have also tried using 128-bit floats, which didn't alter anything noticeable. Is there any way to make my answer more accurate? I think it probably has something to do with how the computer rounds, but I'm not sure how to mess with that. Here is a plot showing the kind of data I'm working with if you aren't familiar with astronomical spectra.

Spectra template (Orange) with Fake 'Observed Spectra' (Blue)

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it might be better on astronomy stack exchange: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Frankly, I'm astonished that the solution looks as good as it does.  My only suggestions would be the same as for any non-linear solution: initial guess and starting point can make a big difference in convergence, change convergence parameters to see if they make a difference.

Comment: @duffymo I'm just worried that it's more of a computing thing than the data itself because I'm not yet working on real, observed data, I'm working on a template, which is why I didn't put it on astro stack.

Comment: Charlie, bear in mind that when you are working with noisy data, the question of what is the "correct" result becomes more subtle. If you have generated the data with F(a) + noise, where a is your parameter and F is some deterministic function, then you must expect that the LS result will not be exactly a, but in some neighborhood, which becomes larger as the magnitude of the noise increases. Try different noise magnitudes -- you should find that you get closer and closer to the nominal value as the noise gets smaller and smaller.

Comment: Incidentally unless your problem is ill-posed (i.e. different parameters yield almost the same goodness of fit), the variation due to changing the precision of the calculation will be much less than the variation due to noise.